# make movie clip with function mouse down in action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

i will make my hammer(movie clip) following cursor and every time I click the mouse / mouse down, the hammer will come down exposed cursor and return to original position. But i just can make the hammer(movie clip) following cursor. How can I do?

```
hammer.startDrag(true);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should create an animation that you want hammer performs when clicking. Then execute that animation whenever user mouse downs.

Let's say hammer has an animation and starts at frame #2 then;

```
private function MainFunction():void
{
    hammerMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, CursorDown);
    hammerMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, CursorUp);
    //and other required events...
}

private function CursorDown(ref:MouseEvent):void
{
    hammerMC.gotoAndPlay(2);//hammerMC.nextFrame();
    //...
}

private function CursorUp(ref:MouseEvent):void
{
    //we do this because we want cursor comes back to default status after we release the mouse button
    //otherwise it sticks to mouse down animation
    hammerMC.gotoAndStop(1);
    //...
}
```

I guess this will do the job enough.

Comment: thanks for your answer @coner, i try it, but error. so, what should i do?

Comment: Please provide these details.